# Changing running video button css

Tags: javascript, css, flash, video-streaming

I'm using a background player that works like this:

```
    function Background(flashID) {
        this.flashID = flashID;
        this.swfRef = null;
        this.onReady = function() { };

        this.registerswfRef = function() {
          if (this.swfRef == null)
            this.swfRef = swfobject.getObjectById(this.flashID);
        };

       this.playMovieByNum = function(movieID) {
       this.registerswfRef();
       this.swfRef.playMovieByNum(movieID);
       };
```

And this order to call the video:

```
var background = new Background('back_1');// id for the backgground movie

          function onReady(id)
          {
              //this function will run when the background has finished loading the xml.
              //console.log('backgorund is now ready '+id); // id is passed from flash file.
          };

        window.onload =function()
        {
            document.getElementById('video1').onclick=function(){background.start(); background.playMovieByNum(1); };
            document.getElementById('video2').onclick=function(){background.start(); background.playMovieByNum(2); };
            document.getElementById('video3').onclick=function(){background.start(); background.playMovieByNum(3); };
            document.getElementById('video4').onclick=function(){background.start(); background.playMovieByNum(4); };
            document.getElementById('video5').onclick=function(){background.start(); background.playMovieByNum(5); };
            document.getElementById('video6').onclick=function(){background.start(); background.playMovieByNum(6); };
            document.getElementById('video7').onclick=function(){background.start(); background.playMovieByNum(7); };
            document.getElementById('video8').onclick=function(){background.start(); background.playMovieByNum(8); };
        };
```

I need the background of the button relative the running video changes color.

For example, if the video "1" is running, the button '#video1' will get the background "#EF4123", if not background is "none".

I tried adding it, but only changes the background when you click on the button:

```
this.playMovieByNum = function(movieID) {
      this.registerswfRef();
      this.swfRef.playMovieByNum(movieID);
      for(i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    if(i == movieID)
        $("#video" + i).css("background", "#EF4123");

    else
        $("#video" + i).css("background", "");
}
    };
```

I need it to change automatically when changing the video also.

You can see this working here:
http://luisgustavoventura.com

Suggestions please.
Thank you.